# Can't add 5th free users in TFS as contributor

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm currently working on a project with a small team of 5 users.
I had a users which email address didn't work, so I added a second email address of his, without removing the previous one. The issue with this is, that when I added the second email address, it counted as the 5th free user.

Now that I deleted his unused email address and try to add another 5th free user, it doesn't allow me add him as a contributor anymore, but as a stakeholder.

So basically first I had it like this:

1. User A
2. User B
3. User C
4. User D
5. User D2

Then I tried adding user E, but I received the following notification:

> NOTE: The user Jef Van Vinckenroye has access to limited functionality
>   as a Stakeholder. Basic access level is required for access to version
>   control and Agile tools.

Now I removed user D2 and added E instead so I have the following:

1. User A
2. User B
3. User C
4. User D
5. User E

But I still get the same error.
Suggestions? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using Visual Studio Team Service not on-premises TFS.

For VSTS, if you haven't paid for any uses, **you will have 5 users who get Basic feature and Unlimited users who get Stakeholder features.** When there's 5 Basic accounts(email address) added to VSTS, the account after will be set to Stakeholder. These 5 accounts are **free**.

And if you want to have more Basic users, you need to pay for them. Please refer to this document for more details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services#expando-need-more-basic-users

### Update:

Please check the User page and add the `Jef Van Vinckenroye` set it to Basic Level. Look in my VSTS User page, I have 7 users, 5 Basic and 2 Stackholder. If I add the `v-gaxiao` account as a Contributor, it will get the error like you. When I change it to Basic at the User page, he could be added to contributor.
[image]

Comment: I'm aware that if I want more basic users I'll have to pay for it, but I added 5 users and when I tried adding a 6th member it failed. Now I deleted a user (so I had 4) and when I want to add the 5th member, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JorisDecraecker You should check the **User page** to see if the `Jef Van Vinckenroye` account is at the Basic level, according to the error, this account maybe at Stackholder. A Stackholder couldn't be added to the **Contributor** group. For more information, please refer to the Update of my reply.

Comment: That totally did the trick! The users button was hidden under the three dots, so I didn't see it! I removed the wrong user there and changed the level of the correct user. Thanks!